# Query run time is taking more time in aurora mysql

Tags: mysql

I am facing performance issue on the below query. The row counts from each table provided below. I am creating group index before running the query.

`select count(*) from temp1`;  - 3864797
`select count(*) from temp2;`  - 36985

create index sav1dx1 on MIS.temp1 (tpid,origin_airport,dest_airport_1,dest_airport_2);
    create index savidx3 on MIS.temp2(tpid,origin_airport,dest_airport_3);

```
CREATE temporary TABLE MIS.Tempfinal engine=Innodb as
select a.tpid,a.origin_airport,a.dest_airport_1,a.dest_airport_2,c.dest_airport_3,a.saving_1,a.saving_2,c.saving_3
from MIS.temp1 a join MIS.temp2 c on  a.tpid = c.tpid and a.origin_airport = c.origin_airport
and a.dest_airport_1 <> c.dest_airport_3 and a.dest_airport_2 <> c.dest_airport_3
```

;

The above query is ending up with 583627364 rows in 3 hrs.

below is the explain output:
Savings_1 as temp1  and SaVings3 as temp2

explain
select a.tpid,a.origin_airport,a.dest_airport_1,a.dest_airport_2,c.dest_airport_3,a.saving_1,a.saving_2,c.saving_3
from MIS.Savings_1 a join MIS.SaVings3 c on  a.tpid = c.tpid and a.origin_airport = c.origin_airport
and a.dest_airport_1 <> c.dest_airport_3 and a.dest_airport_2 <> c.dest_airport_3;

1|SIMPLE|c|ALL|savidx3|||37323|Using where
1|SIMPLE|a|ref|sav1dx1|sav1dx1|18|MIS.c.tpid,MIS.c.origin_airport|1|Using index condition; Using where

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the query plan when you run  [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) on your query.

Comment: Provided the required details above